# After you have an active action type on Facebook, will it require re-approval if you add an object type?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already have the action "viewed" approved.
I want to add another object to it (video, picture)

Will Facebook do another reapproval for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't require re-approval.